# Memory-leaks with CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_AudioInputDeviceCategory)

Tags: c, windows, memory-leaks

When executing the following code, refrence from MSDN, there is some serious memory leaks. I am using vs2015 and Windows 10.

Did I forget to call a Release() or another method to prevent the leak ?

```
#include <ddraw.h>
#include <strmif.h>
#include <uuids.h>
#include <initguid.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids.lib")
void main()
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    while (true)
    {
        // Create the System Device Enumerator.
        HRESULT hr;
        ICreateDevEnum *pSysDevEnum = NULL;
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
            IID_ICreateDevEnum, (void **)&pSysDevEnum);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
           continue;
        }

        // Obtain a class enumerator for the video compressor category.
        IEnumMoniker *pEnumCat = NULL;
        hr = pSysDevEnum->CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_AudioInputDeviceCategory, &pEnumCat, 0);

        if (hr == S_OK)
        {
            pEnumCat->Release();
        }
        pSysDevEnum->Release();
    }

}
```

Comment: How did you verify the existence of a memory leak?

Comment: I can obviously see memory growth from the Task Manager.

Comment: That alone does not constitute a memory leak. Besides, we don't know what value you are looking at. There are multiple values associated with *"memory"* you can choose from in Windows' Task Manager. [Determining Whether a Leak Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541886.aspx) is a helpful read.